# Angular expressions don't work with video.js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, video.js

So I'm using Angular and video.js library. I have a link to a video saved as a variable and neither src nor ngSrc attributes don't work with Angular expressions (e.g ="{{src}}".

Example:

```
<div class="section-video" >
           <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="380" controls
                  data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:380", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
               <source ng-src="{{item.video}}" type='video/mp4'>
           </video>
      </div>
```

jquery:

```
  $(function(){
        if (document.querySelector(".video-js")) {
            var player = videojs(document.querySelector(".video-js"));
        }
    });
```

It works fine if I use an actual link in src such as

```
<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
```

The error I'm getting is

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible
>   source was found for this media.

Anyone has any idea how do I work around this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

HTML:

```
<div class="section-video" >
  <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="380" controls data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:380", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
    <source ng-src="{{trustSrc(item.video)}}" type='video/mp4'>
   </video>
</div>
```

JavaScript (don't forget to inject $sce into your controller):

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
};
```

---

UPDATE:

After doing some research, there appears to be an alternative solution to mine as well that would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="section-video" >
  <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="380" controls data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:380", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
    <source ng-src="{{item.video}}" type='video/mp4' html5vfix>
   </video>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.directive('html5vfix', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            attr.$set('src', attr.vsrc);
        }
    }
});
```

Source: [HERE](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352)

Comment: Unfortunately none of these worked.. Seems like videojs doesn't work with ngSrc at all (when I use it with a link that works with src, it doesn't work anymore). And the application just doesn't want to accept any expressions in a regular src attribute...

Comment: Can you upload a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) of your code? I'm using videojs with ng-src in a project I'm working on just fine with the solution above.

Comment: That's pretty much what I got. I have a file name in item.video like "\file\intro\1501837600116.mp4" which works just fine by itself, but not when evaluated through an expression. I suppose if I'm using ng-src in <source> I need to use ng-if in <video> so that it would wait for angular to load the data, but ng-if breaks video.js as well.. Like, it looks fine but the play button won't work.

Comment: `That's pretty much what I got` - regardless, it still would be helpful to create a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) so that I (or other people trying to help) don't have to go try to recreate it just to try to help. Also, like I said in the response, that works for me so having an example with the same solution that doesn't work would be helpful in addressing what your issue is.